# Gmail app: how can I change the sender address?

Tags: gmail

I'm using Gmail for all mail related stuff, but the main address I use is not my "real" Gmail address, but something like `myname@mydomain.com`.
I have [set up that adress as a sender in Gmail](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370), so every mail that I send from the Gmail web app looks like it's coming from `myname@mydomain.com` (instead of `myname@gmail.com`).

So my question is:
Is it possible to use this sender adress in the Gmail Android app as well?
All mails sent by the Gmail app are sent from `myname@gmail.com` by default and I can't find anything in the settings to change that to my alternate address.
(as I said, it's already set up and working in the web app...the Android app just needs to access this information somehow...)

My phone is a HTC Wildfire with Android 2.2, and version 2.3 of the Gmail app, if that matters.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can tell you absolutely that it can be done; I'm doing it. Do you have both accounts on your phone?

Comment: No I don't, because it's actually only one account, not two. myname@mydomain.com is just set up as an alternate sender adress in my one and only Gmail account, see the link in my question.

Comment: Latest version of GMail is 2.3.5. You probably want to upgrade.

Comment: I want, but I can't. When I access Android Market from my phone, I can't find Gmail at all. From my computer, I can find the Gmail app, but when I try to install it, it says that it's not available for my country (I'm in Germany).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When composing the "From" is a dropdown menu.  It has all the accounts you've added via the webmail interface, and it's had this feature for a long time (you shouldn't need to upgrade).

Comment: Do I have to enable this somehow? When I'm composing, the "From" is **not** a dropdown menu, it just displays my main Gmail address and that's it. No possibility to change it.

Comment: Could it be possible that this is only available in certain countries? I'm in Germany, and I can't upgrade the Gmail app to 2.3.5 either (see my comment under the question)

Comment: I'm afraid it might be. I searched high-and-low for a configuration setting that might control this and came up empty.

Comment: That's unfortunate :(

Comment: Finally (after ove a year), the problem has solved itself. My Gmail app was upgraded to 2.3.6 a few days ago, and now I'm seeing the "From" dropdown menu as well!

Comment: @ChristianSpecht Very strange, but I'm glad!

Comment: It didn't show for me too, but after ditching my cache and data it showed up :-)