# Gmail 4.6 Does not allow "From"/Sender address to be changed to a different email address

Tags: gmail, nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

I did see this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12287/gmail-app-how-can-i-change-the-sender-address), but it was from two years ago, so I know it does not apply to my question.

Before the 10/1/2013 update, I was able to easily switch my sender email account to a different email address, but now, I can't.  I have checked the settings in the app and for the email account.

Is there a setting somewhere in 4.6 that I am missing or did Google kill this feature for the mobile version?

If my question isn't clear, I apologize, and please let me know how I can improve it.

I'm using: Nexus 4, Android 4.3

After further investigation, it may be broken: [gmail forum post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/GWO8FZwqXtA%5B151-175-false%5D)

Thanks.

Comment: No repro here. In the compose window, if I tap my email address I get all of the "Send mail as" options I have for that account, as well as the email address for the other account I have on the device. (Gmail 4.6 on a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.2.)

Comment: That is not happening for me when I compose emails emails.  I thought it may have been limited to replies, but I can't do change it.  I have a Galaxy Nexus at home, so I will update the app there and try it when I get home.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure you have all the accounts set up on the device and syncing Gmail? Have you tried clearing the data/cache of the Gmail app?

Comment: I just cleared the cache.  AND IT WORKS! :)  Forgot about that until I was poking around the app settings.  I was *this close* to rolling back the update.  Thanks @AlEverett.

Comment: Please don't put the solution in your question. Make it an answer and "accept" it so it can act as a signpost for future readers.

Comment: Or, perhaps, this should be a duplicate of [App X isn't working correctly. How can I fix it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13347)

Comment: Where are my manners? :)  I've answered my question.

Comment: My send from menu works, but it's ignored when I click send. Email goes out as my default account.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION: Clear the app cache.  After I cleared the app cache, the "send as" was functioning as it did before the update.

Does this fall under as a duplicate of: [App X Isn't working correctly.  How can I fix it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but it's good to know clearing the cache helped. :)

Comment: Clearing cache and app data didn't work for me.